# Printing text on screen Unreal Engine C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

how can i print not debug text (GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage (-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT(""));) on screen in unreal engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use a widget with text then be able to spawn the widget or always have it open in your level. Create a Widget blueprint and simply add a textbox.